# How can I persist the front end for each user login ? I am making a notes app with mongodb and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, handlebars.js

I've created a collection that fetch the page container html every 30 seconds, now when I call this collection in my backend, and send it to handlebars, Its showing me data but its not in html.

````
router.get("/dashboard/notes", async (req, res) => {
  const userObj = req.session.user;
  const notesHtmlObj = await NotesHTMLModel.findOne({ userId: userObj._id });
  console.log(notesHtmlObj);
  const payloadObj = {
    htmlString: String(notesHtmlObj.notesHTML),
  };
  res.render("notes", payloadObj);
}); ```

**in handlebars I am calling the payloadObj**
````

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="note-wrapper">
      {{htmlString}}
    </div>
```

```
**this is what I am getting in my front end page and not actually html**

````
```<div> &amp;lt;div id="TEST" 01="" class="note"&amp;gt; &amp;lt;h1 class="dynamic-color" contenteditable=""&amp;gt;TEST 01 &amp;lt;/h1&amp;gt; &amp;lt;p contenteditable=""&amp;gt;TEST 01 is a test......................&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt; &amp;lt;div class="button-wrapper"&amp;gt; &amp;lt;i id="highlight" class="fas fa-star"&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/i&amp;gt; &amp;lt;i id="delete" class="far dynamic-color fa-trash-alt"&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/i&amp;gt; &amp;lt;/div&amp;gt; &amp;lt;/div&amp;gt;&amp;lt;div id="TEST" 02="" class="note"&amp;gt; &amp;lt;h1 class="dynamic-color" contenteditable=""&amp;gt;TEST 02&amp;lt;/h1&amp;gt; &amp;lt;p contenteditable=""&amp;gt;TEST 02 is a test......................&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt; &amp;lt;div class="button-wrapper"&amp;gt; &amp;lt;i id="highlight" class="fas fa-star"&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/i&amp;gt; &amp;lt;i id="delete" class="far dynamic-color fa-trash-alt"&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/i&amp;gt; &amp;lt;/div&amp;gt; &amp;lt;/div&amp;gt; </div>```
````

**I tried using handlebar helpers `#each` but its not showing anydata**

Comment: What is the issue actually? There are two questions: one with handle bars and one is to keep data for every user. What you actually want to get answer for?

Comment: It's not a good practice to have HTML rendered as a string. Also, have the data saved in DB should be string as this helps against XSS Attack.